# Circuit Breaker not closing after opening

Tags: java, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resiliency

I have created a circuit breaker with the following config

```
CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold("80f")
                .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
                .maxWaitDurationInHalfOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled(true)
                .build()
```

Code that will open or close the circuit breaker

```
if (CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED.equals(circuitBreaker.getState())) {

                CheckedFunction0<String> saveAltTextSupplier = CircuitBreaker.decorateCheckedSupplier(defaultCircuitBreaker, () -> client.predict(details, throwError));
                Try<String> saveAltTextResult = Try.of(saveAltTextSupplier);
                if(saveAltTextResult != null && saveAltTextResult.isSuccess()){
                    return saveAltTextResult.get();
                }
            
            return null;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Blocking AltText downstream API call due to circuit breaker open");
    }
```

client.predict function details

```
public String predict(AssetBase64 assetBase64, boolean throwError) throws RuntimeException{
        String altText;


        if(throwError) {
            throw new NullPointerException("");
        }else{
            return "";
        }

    }
```

I initially send throwError value as true to simulate error in the method and after multiple request the circuit breaker opens. However, when I set the value as false and start sending request after 10 seconds since the waitDurationInOpenState is 10 seconds the circuit breaker still remains open and doesn't get closed.

It is not even going to Half open state.

Comment: Why that code? Feels like you are doing the job of the circuitbreaker again. Ditch the if statement and just wrap your functional call. If you don't and do what you do now is that it will never be reset as it will never be triggered again. So basically your own code broke things.

Comment: Next to that you are pretty much abusing the `Try` use the `onFailure` and `onSuccess` callbacks rather then this.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful @M.Deinum, I also added 
```CircuitBreaker.State.HALF_OPEN.equals(circuitBreaker.getState())``` to check for half_open state and make calls to the method if it is half open

Comment: You shouldn't check anything. Remove the darn if. The if beats the purpose of the circuitbreaker.